# How to use properties from SCNFloor with Swift and Scenekit?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I can't figure out how to access properties from the Scenekit SCNFloor class using Swift, in objective-c they do it like this:

```
SCNNode*floor = [SCNNode node];
floor.geometry = [SCNFloor floor];
((SCNFloor*)floor.geometry).reflectionFalloffEnd = 10;
```

This creates the floor, how do i acces "reflectionFalloffEnd"?

```
let levelFloor = SCNNode()
levelFloor.geometry = SCNFloor()
```

Thanks

EDIT  Thanks for the quick responses it works now :)

Answer (score 9):

Whether you're in ObjC or Swift, for the compiler to be happy with you using `SCNFloor` properties or methods on a reference, that reference needs to have the type `SCNFloor`.

You can do that inline with a cast:

```
// ObjC
((SCNFloor*)floor.geometry).reflectionFalloffEnd = 10;

// Swift
(levelFloor.geometry as SCNFloor).reflectionFalloffEnd = 10
```

But that can get rather unwieldy, especially if you're going to set a bunch of properties on a geometry. I prefer to just use local variables (or constants, rather, since the references don't need to change):

```
let floor = SCNFloor()
floor.reflectionFalloffEnd = 10
floor.reflectivity = 0.5
let floorNode = SCNNode(geometry: floor)
floorNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: -10.0, z: 0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(floorNode)
```

Answer (score 3):

`(levelFloor.geometry as SCNFloor).reflectionFalloffEnd = 10` is how you would make that cast in Swift - you were almost there!

as an alternative - if you are going to need to access this property often you may end up with a bunch of `as` casts in your code  :)  you may instead prefer to simply declare constants to hold those objects:

```
let levelFloor = SCNNode()
let levelFloorGeometry = SCNFloor()
levelFloor.geometry = levelFloorGeometry

levelFloorGeometry.reflectionFalloffEnd = 10
// and so on as this property of your SCNNode's geometry needs to change throughout your app
```